# Object literal variable is undefined inside statement that creates the object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, object-literal

I'm playing around with Knockout JS, and in this code sample:

```
var data = 
    {
      allMakes: ko.observableArray([ 
        { name: "Toyota" }, 
        { name: "Fiat"} 
      ]),
      allModels: ko.observableArray([
        { name: "Corolla", make: "Toyota" },
        { name: "Celica", make: "Toyota" },
        { name: "Avensis", make: "Toyota" },
        { name: "Uno", make: "Fiat" },
        { name: "Bravo", make: "Fiat" }
      ])
    };

var myViewModel = 
    {
      makes : data.allMakes,
      models: ko.computed(function() {
        if (!myViewModel.selectedMake())
          return;

        // TODO: filter models by selected make
      }),
      selectedModel: ko.observable(""),
      selectedMake: ko.observable("")
    };

/* Uncomment it to work
myViewModel.models = ko.computed(function() {
if (!myViewModel.selectedMake())
          return;

        // TODO: filter models by selected make
      });
*/

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

http://jsbin.com/upaxum/8/edit

we can see that I try to access **myViewModel** variable inside models: ko.computed . However myViewModel is undefined when this computed observable runs. And I don't know why?

However if I create **models** computed observable in next statement, **myViewModel** variable is defined. Why is that?

EDIT: one of the answers suggests that I'm accessing the object before it is created. So how come that this code snippet works?

```
var myViewModel = 
    {
      myFnk : function()
      {
        console.log(myViewModel);
      }
    };

myViewModel.myFnk();
```

http://jsbin.com/eyutip/1/edit

Comment: what about trying  if (!this.selectedMake()) ?

Comment: this is set to window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that trips me up from time to time. **ko.computed executes once as soon as it is defined**. It does this so that it knows which variables it needs to subscribe to watch for changes.

So in this code

```
models: ko.computed(function() {
    if (!myViewModel.selectedMake())
        return;

    // TODO: filter models by selected make
})
```

myViewModel is accessed before it has been assigned to in the `var myViewModel =` line because the ko.computed is executing the function as soon as it is defined.

In your second example you are executing the function *AFTER* myViewModel has been defined so that is why it works. If you wanted to replicate this in your first example you might do something like:

```
var myViewModel = 
{
  makes : data.allMakes,
  selectedModel: ko.observable(""),
  selectedMake: ko.observable("")
};

myViewModel.models = ko.computed(function() {
    if (!myViewModel.selectedMake())
      return;

    // TODO: filter models by selected make
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
alert("This is " + myViewModel);
```

`myViewModel` hasn't yet been defined--you're still in the process of defining it! What exactly are you trying to do? What's the original reason that you want to be able to access the view model from within itself? If you tell us this, I'm pretty sure we can find a more idiomatic way of doing what you need to do.

---

#### Edit (after OP's edit)

In order to be able to refer to parts of your view model from other parts of the view model, use the `self` pattern (as [recommended in the Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing_this)):

```
function myViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.makes = data.allMakes;
    self.models = ko.computed(function() {
        if (!self.selectedMake())
            return;
        // TODO: do something with self.selectedMake()
        });
    self.selectedModel = ko.observable("");
    self.selectedMake = ko.observable("")
}
```

Comment: Well I've narrowed down code to the minimum. Basically I want to check if myViewModel.selectedMake. I'll update the question

Comment: "...myViewModel hasn't yet been defined--you're still in the process of defining it ?..." SO why second code snippet works? I think that the reason why it does not work has something to do with a Knockout JS and things it does behind the scenes

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked a big problem with my example! View models should be defined as functions, not as objects. Try it now.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks. However... I can create them as constructor function or as object literal, this is obvious. But self patter is not a solution to my question - it just a approach to preserve a context of this. Yet, in my code snippet object literal variable is undefined, even though (when looking at second simple snippet) I thought I should be and it should work. So I would like to know this is happening